Is php debug in VSCode supported on M3 chip running Sequoia?
I recently migrated from Macbook Intel to Macbook M3 chip running Seqouia 15.0.1. I downloaded and installed the Apple Silicon Visual Studio Code (somehow I ended up with the 'Universal' version 1.9.4.0) and enabled the PHP Debug extension (there are several, I ended up with the xdebug.org extension). A launch.json file (shown below) was auto-generated via a link. I can set breakpoints in the displayed php (8.2.2) code. When I 'Start debugging' (Listen for Xdebug) then execute the code, it does not stop at breakpoints. I note that the MAMP7 for Apple Silicon tool does not support Apache at this time, so I am running with Nginx. After searching through many sites and questions, I cannot find a solution dealing with this. The php.ini file, as I understand it, applies to the Apache server, so changes to that have no effect. What am I missing?
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}


A working xdebug extension for Apple Silicon was found and installed using using the following command.
arch -arm64 sudo pecl install xdebug

This installed xdebug to my local machine's php (not MAMP's), so more was needed to get it to work in MAMP. I was incorrect about the php.ini file pertaining to Apache only; I edited the MAMP php.ini file for the php version I am working with, and removed the comment character from the zend-extension rule. I then had to change the xdebug.so location from its default to the location the xdebug install utility echoed back:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.12_1/pecl/20230831/xdebug.so

After that, the VSCode debugger properly halted on breakpoints. There doesn't seem to be a single source of information on how to do this for Apple Silicon, so I hope this may help others.
